# Multiple Modules/Package in a JHipster app?

Tags: jhipster

I am working on designing entities and relationships amount of them of application. The JDL file is getting bigger and bigger. It has six pages right now. I am wondering how to separate them based on business functionality with JHipster. A microservices system should be used due to the various functionality. Because of some restrictions, I need to build it as a monolith application at least for now. If my understanding is correct, a JHipster monolith application can't have multiple modules/packages. Any alternative approaches?

Comment: You're reaching the limits of the tool, it's probably time to leave it and do some manual refactoring applying DDD ideas like in https://github.com/odrotbohm/moduliths. Some probably could advise you to write a blueprint but I think it will require some effort that will keep you away from implementing your business requirements. JHipster team has been thinking too it several times and it's not easy https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11122

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks very much for your information. The moduliths project is interesting. I will take a look in detail.